# getting p2p_device_address from wpa_cli status

Tags: python, linux, wpa

Is there any way to get different information from the command "wpa_cli status", e.g., 
p2p_device_address, ssid etc. separately, ?

What i am currently using is by calling wpa_cli from a python script:

```
import subprocess 
cmd =  "wpa_cli -i wlan3 status"
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, close_fds=True)
output = p.stdout.read()
```

my output is printed out as:

```
bssid=xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
ssid=lifa_2
id=0
mode=station
pairwise_cipher=CCMP
group_cipher=CCMP
key_mgmt=WPA2-PSK
wpa_state=COMPLETED
ip_address=192.168.0.104
p2p_device_address=xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
address=xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
uuid=xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxx
```

what i want here is the p2p_device_address only, i.e

```
output = p.stdout.read() # in this case ouput must be a string containing only the address
```

what i am thinking of my self is to use str.split() and select line 9, and do some string manipulation to get the id, however that will be a hack, it will be much smother to let wpa_cli to return the address only, if there any?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `pipe` in Linux:

```
import subprocess 
cmd =  "wpa_cli -i wlan3 status | grep ip_address"
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, close_fds=True)
output = p.stdout.read()
```

Then you will get the only line with `ip_address`.